# A game implementation in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, connect-four

I have the following Connect 4 implementation. Is there a way to refactor it and maybe make it better. It's a fully working solution. However, I see that the correct result is not returned in certain cases like the following. In this case 1 should have won since there are `four_in_a_row` from the right hand side:

```
Team 0: Your turn, please choose column: 2
[' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ']
[' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '0']
[' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '0', '1']
[' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '1', '0']
['0', ' ', ' ', ' ', '1', '0', '1']
['0', '0', ' ', '1', '1', '1', '0']
```

I might be missing some edge cases and would be great if I could get this code reviewed and some sample code of how to refactor the same. My `get_diagonals` function might be the one causing the issue. 
The following is the code:

```
"""
Module Docstring
This is an implementation of the
Connect 4 game, where each user
Can enter 0 and 1. A user wins if
There is 4 in a row match either
Horizontally, vertically or diagonally.
"""
class ConnectFour():

    def __init__(self, height, width):
        self.height = height
        self.width = width
        self.board = [[' ' for x in range(width)] for y in range(height)]

    def get_column(self, index):
        """
        Returns a column at the specified index
        :param index: int Index at which column will be returned
        :return: List[String]
        """
        return [i[index] for i in self.board]

    def get_row(self, index):
        """
        Returns a row at the specified index
        :param index: Index at which row will be returned
        :return:
        """
        return self.board[index]

    def get_diagonals(self):
        """
        :return:  List of all digonal positions from top right to bottom left
        and from top left to bottom right
        """
        diagonals = []
        # For all diagonals from (3,0) top right to (0,3) bottom left
        for i in range(self.height + self.width - 1):
            diagonals.append([])
            for j in range(max(i - self.height + 1, 0), min(i + 1, self.height)):
                diagonals[i].append(self.board[self.height - (i - j + 1)][j])

        # For all diagonals from (0,0) top left to (3,3) bottom right
        for i in range(self.height + self.width - 1):
            diagonals.append([])
            for j in range(max(i - self.height + 1, 0), min(i + 1, self.height)):
                diagonals[i].append(self.board[i - j][j])



        return diagonals

    def make_move(self, team, col):
        """
        Simply a move and places 1/0 is the specified postion for the team in turn
        :param team: String  The team currently playing either '0' or '1'
        :param col: String The col selected by the team
        :return: board: List[List[Str]]
        """
        if ' ' not in self.get_column(col):
            return self.board
        i = self.height - 1
        # check if current index is empty
        while self.board[i][col] != ' ':
            i -= 1
        self.board[i][col] = team
        return self.board

    def check_win(self):
        """
        :return: String  the board and returns winning team
        that contain matched 4 in a row determining the team that won
        """
        four_in_a_row = [['0','0','0','0'],['1','1','1','1']]
        # Check for 4 in a row in rows
        for i in range(self.height):
            for j in range(self.width -3):
                if self.get_row(i)[j:j+4] in four_in_a_row:
                    return self.board[i][j]

        # Check for 4 in a row in cols
        for i in range(self.width):
            for j in range(self.height - 3):
                if self.get_column(i)[j:j+4] in four_in_a_row:
                    return self.board[j][i]

        # Check for 4 in a row in diagonals
        for i in self.get_diagonals():
            for j, _ in enumerate(i):
                if i[j:j + 4] in four_in_a_row:
                    return i[j]
        #Otherwise if no case wins
        return None

    def start_game(self, game):
        """
        The method that simulates the gameplay and returns which team won
        :param board: The board in which the game is currently being played
        :return: String The team that won
        """
        while True:
            for i in game.board:
                print(i)
            if game.check_win() is not None:
                break
            col = int(input("Team 0: Your turn, please choose column: ")) - 1
            game.make_move('0',col)

            for i in game.board:
                print(i)
            if game.check_win() is not None:
                break
            col = int(input("Team 1: Your turn please choose column: ")) - 1
            game.make_move('1',col)

        if game.check_win():
            print(f'Congrats team {game.check_win()} !')
            return f'Team {game.check_win()} has won. Thank you for playing!!!'
        else:
            return None

if __name__ == '__main__':
    height = 6
    width = 7
    game = ConnectFour(height, width)
    game.start_game(game)
```

Thanks a lot in advance for all the advice!

Comment: If your code isn't working as intended, this is probably better off at Stack Overflow. See [on topic for CR](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). I'm having trouble reconciling "It's a fully working solution. However, I see that the correct result is not returned in certain cases".